# The usage of "on the condition that"

Tags: conditionals

I know that I can use the phrase 'on the condition that' with if clauses such as

- *He agreed to work on Saturdays on condition that he was paid overtime.*

But I'm not sure if I can use this structure like,

- *I would recommend it to all ages on the condition that they’ve watched the other two films of the series.*

I've used the word 'would' in the main clause but in the if clause I've used a present perfect tense. Would that be a correct usage? I also wonder whether I should use 'on the condition that' or 'on condition that. I'd be grateful if you could answer those questions above.

Comment: It's a heavy-duty, ponderous phrase. Possibly justified in your first example, but sounding a pedantic replacement for 'if' in the second.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So is it correct to use it like in the second example, apart from the meaning?

Comment: 'On the condition that' sounds so formal that one wonders if there will be a stiff penalty for watching the films in the wrong order. Better avoided.

Comment: I would recommend it to *anyone* if they have already watched the other two films *in* the series.

Comment: In a negotiation, you might ask for X on the condition that Y. You would not *recommend X on the condition that Y* unless you're making a deal, and someone owes you Y. *On the condition that* describes a requirement, not a suggestion. That's why it does fit a film suggestion.

Comment: *On the condition that* normally introduces a necessary condition, while *if* introduces a sufficient condition (at least when used carefully - in casual, everyday usage it might not be very clear whether it introduces a sufficient or a necessary condition or both).

Comment: If the condition is spelled out, it could be 'on the condition that'. If not, it can be 'on condition that'. I recommend and  would recommend resounds the language function, and often both are interchangeable, but 'I should recommend...' has a little different sense, like make it emphatic, or adding an individualistic view etc.

Comment: As hinted by others, *if* does not mean precisely the same as *on the condition that*. The latter has more of a sense of *if and only if*.

Comment: Then there’s *provided that* and *given that.*

Comment: I would use "but it would help if" instead of "on condition that". Even if they have not watched the previous films, it is still recommendable to all ages I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the word "condition" this is not a conditional sentence, in case you're wondering if it should have used the past perfect, as in "I would recommend it if I had enjoyed it." This "would" is the "polite request" version and is not needed grammatically. "On the condition that" is a bit wordy and could be replaced by "if."

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is grammatical, but "on the condition that" is not in the proper *register* for your sentence and the present perfect is overkill.  Here's an exaggerated example of what I mean:

> You can have ice cream for dessert but only on condition that you have finished your peas.

A simple "only if" would do and the present perfect is unnecessary:

> You can have ice cream for dessert but only if you finish your peas.

Also, what does having seen the first two films of the series have to do with the film's suitability for all ages?